# Software for copying articles from a certain website and save them as a word or pdf file

Tags: automation

I want a automation software that can do the following.

Triggers:- Email push notification, or manual start up

Follow the links in the email go to the website and copy the article on that link  and save it as a word file.

Answer (score 2):

[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) can be invoked from the command line with a URL and a destination file name to produce a wide variety of output files, including docx and pdf *(with some additional dependencies for pdf)*.

Obviously the results will vary depending on the web site layout as will the link that you need to provide.

When I ran:

```
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38149/software-for-copying-articles-from-a-certain-website-and-save-them-as-a-word-or -o webscrape.docx
```

I get, (without word installed), a file that looks like:
[image]

But when I run:

```
pandoc http://www.nationalgeographic.com/magazine/2016/12/orangutans-behaviors-borneo-sumatra/ -o webscrape.docx
```

I get a document that looks in part like:
[image]

Admittedly the first couple of pages were full of navigation details but that was easily deleted or you could almost certainly adjust the URL to get the content only.